# Differentiation calculation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

$L(E)$ espace fonction continuous and linear 
$$\begin{array}{llll}
\psi:& L(E)\times E&\longrightarrow& E\\
&(u,x)&\longrightarrow &u(x)
\end{array}$$
 proved  the application $\psi$ differentiable and calculer this differential ?

Comment: Hint: For $u,d\in L(E)$ and $x,h\in E$ we have $(u+d)(x+h) - u(x) = d(x) + u(h) + d(h)$. Is $d(h) = \mathcal o(\max(\|d\|, \|h\|))$?

Comment: the differential of $\psi$ not $u+d$

Comment: For the differential of $\psi$ you need to computes $\psi(u+d, x+h) - \psi(u,x) = (u+d)(x+h) - u(x).$ :)

Comment: Please more hint .........

Comment: $\|d(h)\| \le \|d\| \|h\| = \min(\|d\|, \|h\|) \max(\|d\|, \|h\|)$.

Comment: so the differential of $\psi$ is $d(x)$

Comment: $\psi'(u,x)[d,h] = d(x) + u(h)$

Comment: But $d$ and $u$   that of the same espace , what is the difference between $u(h)$ and $d(h)$

Comment: $u$ and $x$ are fixed. For differentiable at $(u,x)$ you need to show $$\psi(u+d,x+h) - \psi(u,x) - \psi'(u,x)[d,h] = \mathcal o(\max(\|d\|, \|u\|))$$ for $(d,h)\to(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $\psi: V \to R$ is differentiable at $p \in D$ when 
$$\lim_{v \to 0} \psi(p+v) - \psi(p) = L(p)v + r(v)$$
and $\frac{r(v)}{\|v\|}\to 0$ as $v \to 0$. (Here $V$ and $R$ are  normed vector spaces)

To check for the existence of a derivative you take a general $v$  and try to guess  $L(x): V \to R$.

In our case take $ p = (u,x)$ and $v= (d,h)$ (as in  user251257 )

$$ \psi(p+v) - \psi(p) = \psi(u+d, x+h) - \psi(u,x) = (u+d)(x+h) - u(x) = u(x+h) + d(x+h) - u(x) = u(x)+ u(h) + d(x) + d(h) - u(x) = u(h) + d(x) + d(h) $$

Since $\|(d,h)\| \geq \frac{|h|}{2}$ it is reasonable to guess that the product $|d(h)| \leq \|d\||h|$ is an error term, so take $L(u,x)(d,h):= u(h)+ d(x)$  (note this is a linear transformation). Moreover

$$  \psi(u+d, x+h) - \psi(u,x) -L(u,x)(d,h) =  d(h) $$ 
where
 $$ \frac{|d(h)|}{||(d,h)||} \leq \|d\| \frac{1}{2}\xrightarrow[(d,h) \to 0]{} 0$$